# Thermostat wiring splice

Tags: wiring, thermostat

I need to relocate a thermostat and have the additional wire needed but I am not sure of the ideal way to "join" the cable sections.

Will using wire nuts and zip tie be good enough?

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that most thermostats control the equipment with thin low-voltage wires (24V) which are not particularly dangerous, but some electric heat has line-level voltage going to the thermostat (normal electricity wires, 120V or 240V) which needs to be properly installed like any other live electric wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A butt splice connector, or twist-on wire connector would be fine. Just make sure you use connectors that are designed for the size, and number of wires being connected.

[image: Butt splice connector]
[image: Twist-on wire connector]

---

Technically, you should probably either pull all new wiring, so that it's continuous from HVAC to thermostat. Or put the connections in a junction box, that is left accessible.

Comment: ok, I'll use twist-on wire connector. Is there a code that tells in what height the thermostat need to be?

Comment: @Grasper Not that I'm aware of. Check the manufacturer's documentation, they might recommend an installation height.

Comment: Are low voltage connections exempt from accessibility regulations,  I.E.not burying the connections in a wall?

Comment: @HerrBag Not exactly.

Comment: @HerrBag To my knowledge, I don't think NEC covers 24 volt HVAC control wiring, but I could be wrong.  If they do cover it, I've seen thousands of violations. I don't think I've ever seen 24 volt thermostat wiring terminated in an enclosure, nor have I seen 24 volt thermostats that would attach to standard size boxes.

Comment: I did it yesterday and all works fine. Can a wrongly wired thermostat damage a furnace? I'm just wondering in case some wire would get disconnected. Would the thermostat detect it and show some error on display?

Comment: @Grasper If a wire gets disconnected, the HVAC system will not operate properly.  If wires short together, it's possible to cause damage, or the heating/cooling/fan systems could come on.

Comment: @Tester101, well in that case I can only hope nothing bad will happen as it is with everything. I'm sure I connected it correctly but you never know what could have gone wrong in the process, maybe wire cracked. I don't fully understand why in USA use single wire instead bunched strands

Answer (score 2):

Wire nuts or Butt Connectors work fine. I would ziptie or knot the ends together to prevent them from being pulled apart.

There is no issues with shorting. If the wires short your furnace will turn on. Thats all the thermostat does anyway.

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT use a crimp connector on solid conductors.

NASA approves crimp connectors only on stranded wire, and specifically prohibits the use of crimp connectors on solid wire (see 4.3.4 on page 23 of the link below). Solid wire should be spliced by soldering; or in the building trade, wire nuts may be acceptable.

https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/codeq/doctree/87394.pdf

As with anything else, consider the consequence of primary failure (the thing doesn't function as intended), and secondary failure (house freezes because thermostat failed to call for heat, or fire from high resistance due to improper connection).

BETTER CHOICE for the DIY person is a new connector from Ideal which is approved by UL, made in USA, and available at Home Depot and Amazon ... Spliceline. More expensive than soldering and heatshrink, but easier and faster for sure; although a little bulkier.

http://www.idealind.com/content/pdfs/sell-sheets/p-5003_spliceline_brochure.pdf

Comment: Solder only connections are not allowed in the U.S.. A wire nut would be acceptable.

Comment: Crimp connectors are not designed for solid wire. they don't bond well at all. I know this from experience (and so does NASA).